# Unable to implement Generic interface function in kotlin

Tags: android, function, kotlin, generics, interface

I have created interface to separate domain from data layer.

```
interface EditRepository<T> : Repository {    
    fun <P, R> post(postRequest: P): LiveData<ResponseData<R>>
    fun <E, R> edit(editRequest: E): LiveData<ResponseData<R>>
    fun <D, R> delete(deleteRequest: D): LiveData<ResponseData<R>>
}
```

Each function should have it's own generic types(request and response)
After i try to implement this interface methods , I replace generic types with my own types and seem they are not working as it is unable to import my type inside angle brackets of new overriden function(pointed below on screenshot). And i do not know what I am doing wrong here. Why i can't override generic interface function?

[image]

If i try manually import my type, it refuses to accept my function as overiden

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can't change type of override function-level generic. As workaround you can make class cast

```
override fun <P, R> post(postRequest: Response<P>): LiveData<Response<R>> = liveData(IO){
    ........
    emit(ResponseData.SuccessResponse(...) as ResponseData<R>)
}
```

but you'll get lint warning *Unchecked cast:*

In other hand you can use type-level generic

```
interface EditRepository<D,E,P,R> : Repository {
    fun post(postRequest: P): LiveData<ResponseData<R>>
    fun edit(editRequest: E): LiveData<ResponseData<R>>
    fun delete(deleteRequest: D): LiveData<ResponseData<R>>
}
```

and specify required types. But with Retrofit type-level generics causes **IllegalArgumentException: Type parameters are unsupported**

Comment: this becomes a bit clumpsy when you need to reuse same method twice. for example edit comment, edit subcomment would have different types, response, logic etc

Comment: @ВіталійШимко Yes. Using generics with interface is a bit clumpsy